# Is it possible to create a SAS code from a dataset with a list of variables to test?

Tags: sas

I have the dataset `LIST` like this:

```
ID  VARIABLE_TO_TEST
AAA PIPPO
AAA PLUTO
AAA PAPERINO
BBB PLUTO
BBB PAPERINO
CCC PIPPO
```

and another dataset `HAVE` like this:

```
ID  PIPPO PLUTO PAPERINO
AAA xxx   yyy   NULL
BBB NULL  xxx   yyyy
CCC zzz   NULL  NULL
```

The dataset `LIST` contains a list of variables to test.
If a variable in `LIST` for a given `ID` is missing, a new corresponding flag should be created with the value 1.
If it is not missing, the flag should have the value 0.
If a variable is not present in `LIST` for a given `ID`, the corresponding flag should be missing.
The variables are a lot.
The IDs are a lot.

It is possible to transform `LIST` in a code that does:

```
If ID = "AAA" then do;
 IF missing(PIPPO) then FLAG_PIPPO = 1; else FLAG_PIPPO = 0;
 IF missing(PLUTO) then FLAG_PLUTO = 1; else FLAG_PLUTO = 0;
 IF missing(PAPERINO) then FLAG_PAPERINO = 1; else FLAG_PAPERINO = 0;
end; 
If ID = "BBB" then do;
 IF missing(PLUTO) then FLAG_PLUTO = 1; else FLAG_PLUTO = 0;
 IF missing(PAPERINO) then FLAG_PAPERINO = 1; else FLAG_PAPERINO = 0;
end; 
If ID = "CCC" then do;
 IF missing(PIPPO) then FLAG_PIPPO = 1; else FLAG_PIPPO = 0;
end;
```

in other to get the dataset `WANT`, like this:

```
ID  PIPPO PLUTO PAPERINO FLAG_PIPPO FLAG_PLUTO FLAG_PAPERINO
AAA xxx   yyy   NULL     0          0          1
BBB xyz   NULL  yyyy     NULL       1          0
CCC zzz   NULL  xxxx     0          NULL       NULL
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to use that dataset to generate that code. Just use a data step to write the code. You can simplify the code by using fact that MISSING() function already returns 1 or 0.

Let's make a list of variables to test per id.

```
data list ;
  input ID $ VAR :$32. ;
cards;
AAA PIPPO
AAA PLUTO
AAA PAPERINO
BBB PLUTO
BBB PAPERINO
CCC PIPPO
;
```

Now we can use that data to generate code:

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set list ;
  by id;
  file code ;
  if first.id then put 'IF ID=' id :$quote. 'THEN DO;' ;
  put '  FLAG_' var '=MISSING(' var ');' ;
  if last.id then put 'END;' ;
run;
```

Results:

```
IF ID="AAA" THEN DO;
  FLAG_PIPPO =MISSING(PIPPO );
  FLAG_PLUTO =MISSING(PLUTO );
  FLAG_PAPERINO =MISSING(PAPERINO );
END;
IF ID="BBB" THEN DO;
  FLAG_PLUTO =MISSING(PLUTO );
  FLAG_PAPERINO =MISSING(PAPERINO );
END;
IF ID="CCC" THEN DO;
  FLAG_PIPPO =MISSING(PIPPO );
END;
```

Now just use that code in a data step.

```
data want;
  set have;
%include code / source2;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table and tranpose the results...

```
data list ;
  input ID $3.
        VARIABLE_TO_TEST $10.
        ;
datalines ;
AAA PIPPO
AAA PLUTO
AAA PAPERINO
BBB PLUTO
BBB PAPERINO
CCC PIPPO
;
run ;

data have ;
  infile cards dlm='|' missover ;
  input ID $3. (PIPPO PLUTO PAPERINO) (:$4.) ;
datalines ;
AAA|xxx|yyy| 
BBB| |xxx|yyyy
CCC|zzz| | 
;
run ;

data want1 ;
  set have ;
  /* load the lookup list into hash table, multidata:y as >1 record per ID [hash key] */
  if 0 then set list ;
  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    declare hash lst(dataset:'list',multidata:'y') ;
    lst.definekey('ID') ;
    lst.definedata('VARIABLE_TO_TEST') ;
    lst.definedone() ;
  end ;

  call missing(VARIABLE_TO_TEST) ;
  /* loop over all the variables to test for this ID */
  do while(lst.do_over(key:ID) = 0) ; 
    /* vvaluex() to dynamically resolve VARIABLE_TO_TEST value > variable > value */
    var_value = vvaluex(VARIABLE_TO_TEST) ;
    flag = missing(var_value) ; 
    var_flag = cats('FLAG_',VARIABLE_TO_TEST) ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;

proc transpose data=want1 out=want2 (drop=_NAME_) ;
  by ID ;
  id var_flag ;
  var flag ;
run ;

data want ;
  merge have want2 ;
  by ID ;
  drop var_value flag var_flag VARIABLE_TO_TEST ;  
run ;
```

[image: Inputs & Output]

Comment: Your code gives me an error "ERROR: Unknown method DO_OVER for DATASTEP.HASH at line 63 column 12." Maybe I have a too old version of SAS (9.3).

Comment: Yeah `hash.do_over()` is a 9.4 thing... can be refactored to use 9.3 hash functions though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll try when I have time to play with it.